# Событие прокрутки колесика мышки

Tags: java, android, мышь

Здравствуйте.Имеется класс унаследованый от View.В нем есть обработка прокрутки(GestureDetector,Scroller) по событию onTouch.Но это дело не работает для мышки.Кручу колесо а прокрутка не идет.В интернете не нашел событие которое отвечает за мышку.Подскажите как обработать колесико мышки.

Comment: http://jollydroid.ru/notebook/2017-01-17-Keyboard-Mouse-Joystick

Answer (score 1):

Надо ставить слушатель `View.OnGenericMotionListener()` и ловить событие [ACTION_SCROLL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_SCROLL)

Работает с API level >= 12

Comment: Это дело с GestureDetector не работает